# File contains no section headers. Installing Plone 4.3

Tags: plone, buildout

I was looking for an answer to this on the Internet, but no luck on finding it.

I'm on Debian wheezy x86, using python2.7m zope2 already installed, I'm just trying to isntall plone 4.3 through a `buildout.cfg` file, but this is my traceback:

```
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/tmpvPVuPQ/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1941, in main
user_defaults, command, args)
File "/tmp/tmpvPVuPQ/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 221, in __init__
data['buildout'].copy(), override, set()))
File "/tmp/tmpvPVuPQ/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1578, in _open
downloaded)
File "/tmp/tmpvPVuPQ/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1558, in _open
result = zc.buildout.configparser.parse(fp, filename, _default_globals)
File "/tmp/tmpvPVuPQ/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/configparser.py", line 207, in parse
raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.1/, line: 1
'<html>\r\n'
```

This is my buildout.cfg:

```
[buildout]

extends =
    http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.1/

parts =
    instance

[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
user = admin:admin
http-address = 8080
eggs =
    Plone
    Pillow
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.1/versions.cfg`

```
[buildout]

extends =
    http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.1/versions.cfg
```

You miss the `/versions.cfg` at end of your url.

`http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.1`returns only a directory listing, not a `cfg`, from which you can extend in your buildout configuration.

Comment: Awesome, in the documentation i've read it is not specified, duh... Thank you

Comment: Where did you get your informations? which docu? This should be fixed!

Comment: Yeah I guess so, look here: http://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/requirements.html#minimal-build

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me but using Plone 4.2 and it was due to download.zope.org web site that was down

I solved downloading versions.cfg

```
check URL on buildout.cfg

extends =
#     http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2/versions.cfg
     myLocalVersionsFile.cfg
```

and changing the extends section on it

```
extends = http://dist.plone.org/versions/zopetoolkit-1-0-7-zopeapp-versions.cfg
          http://dist.plone.org/versions/zope-2-13-15-versions.cfg

#          http://download.zope.org/zopetoolkit/index/1.0.7/zopeapp-versions.cfg
#          http://download.zope.org/Zope2/index/2.13.15/versions.cfg
```

Hope this help